# Efficiently merge two objects in python

Tags: python, pointers, object, merge

I have a two objects that I want to merge in such a way that all references to the two merged objects now point to the one merged object.

```
#What I want
listOfObjects=[obj1, obj1, obj2, obj2, obj3]
mergeObjects(obj1, obj2)
#now
listofObjects==[merged, merged, merged, merged, obj3]
```

One way to accomplish it is this:

```
def mergeObjects(obj1, obj2):
    obj1.property1+=obj2.property1
    obj1.property2+=obj2.property2
    obj2=obj1
```

However, this has the downside that rather than having one merged object, I have a merged object and an identical copy of it. My program will merge dozens of objects with each other, so this will consume far too much memory.

Another way is:

```
listOfObjects=[obj1, obj1, obj2, obj2, obj3]
mergeObjects(obj1, obj2)
for i in range(len(listOfObjects)):
    if (listOfObjects[i]==obj2):
        listOfObjects[i]==obj1
#now
listofObjects==[merged, merged, merged, merged, obj3]
#and obj2 is now free to be garbage collected
```

However, there are multiple references to these objects and iterating over every one of them each time I merge an object is also not optimal.

One thing I thought of is if I could use pointers. I could instead store a list of pointers to objects and then write:

```
def mergeObjects(obj1_pointer, obj2_pointer):
    obj1=&obj1_pointer
    obj2=&obj2_pointer
    obj1.property1+=obj2.property1
    obj1.property2+=obj2.property2
    obj2_pointer=obj1_pointer
    #let's say the pointers are themselves objects so now we have:

    listOfPointers==[obj1_pointer, obj1_pointer, obj1_pointer, obj1_pointer, obj3_pointer]
    #obj1_pointer is now pointing to the merged object
    #obj2 now has no references so is free to be deleted
```

Where I'm using & as the dereference operator.

So would writing my own pseudopointer object with a dereference method that returned an object be an efficient solution?

If not is there a cleaner way to do this (change object 1 to merged object, then have all references to object 2 instead be a reference to object 1)?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to accomplish... and I'm not sure you do either.

Comment: "I have a two objects that I want to merge in such a way that all references to the two merged objects now point to the one merged object." - not possible. Why do you want to do this? There's probably a better way to design your program. You might want to use a [union-find data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure), for example.

Comment: if you have a list of `[x,y,z]` and you want to merge x and y, there is no way to change all pointers to y to the merged object without directly changing the pointers in the list (so mylist[i] = merged)

Comment: Python doesn't really have C-like pointers. In fact, it doesn't even have C-like variables, in the sense of a named region of RAM that contains a data structure. Instead, it has objects that may be (or may not be) bound to names. A name is effectively a dictionary key and the object is the associated value. You will work more effectively with Python if you forget about pointers and embrace Python's data model. You may find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen The problem with mylist[i]=merged is that objects will be merged quite frequently, so I can't afford to be constantly updating each reference.

Comment: @user2357112 that might be the most natural data structure for what I want, thank you. I'm not completely sure yet, so I'll get back once I've implemented something.

Comment: @user2357112 The Union-find data structure perfectly addresses my needs, if you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: FWIW, I posted that info above because we often get Python questions on SO from people who are fresh from C (or similar languages) and still stuck in that mindset, which can make it hard for them to see a Pythonic way to organize / manipulate their data.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Python data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [union-find data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) is a good way of doing something like this. It groups objects into sets and picks an element of each set to serve as a representative. It supports two operations:

- *find*, which takes an object and returns the representative of that object's set, and
- *union*, which takes two objects and joins their sets into one set. One of the sets' representatives becomes the representative of the combined set.

You can use the representatives to track the merged properties. Implemented the usual way as a [disjoint-set forest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure#Disjoint-set_forests) with union by rank and path compression, the operations are effectively amortized constant time, and there are no problems with merged sets unmerging. (If you tried to do this with the built-in `set` and `set.union`, you'd get merged sets unmerging and really slow operations.)

---

As for actually merging all of two objects' references to point to one object, there's no way to do that. Your pointer idea has its own problems; even if Python supported pointers, you'd end up with previously-merged pointers unmerging when you try to merge one with a third pointer.